# OOP architect a series of events upon user creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, architecture

I'm writing an application where upon user account creation I want a series of events to happen - send gift, send email, etc. My question is in what way have you tackled a problem like this structurally, dependency injection?, observers? or did you just create a method that would handle all of those events? We have a user registration service, but i'm concerned that the more events we add the more random dependencies we will get.

Comment: **Observers**: no, they are deprecated and it is difficult to find out if an object is observed. **Registration service** (service object): definitely! If you have this pattern, you can simply create other service objects that will be called in that Registration Service (ex: in `RegistrationService#perform` you could call `UserRegistration::SendWelcomeEmail.new(self.user).perform if self.user.allow_email_reception?`)

Answer (score 2):

For user registration it's worth publishing an domain event to be handled by different subsystems. Thus, your objects are completely decoupled. But event driven architecture has its price -- it's a way harder to debug and understand and requires some discipline.

If decoupling is not a goal, you may use decorator pattern by wrapping your service with additional behavior:

```
registration_service = WellconeNotification.new(UserRegistration.new)
registration_service.call(params)
```

The key idea here is to separate dependencies and parameters. I found very convenient to use constructor for dependencies and method arguments for parameters.

This approach implies a bit harder dependency management and kind of service locator. I recommend looking at dry-container and dry-auto_inject gems.

Writing all the code in one service object may be reasonable first step if you don't have a lot of business logic or still gathering requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good situation to use ActiveRecord Callbacks

URL: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html

I would read that decide which callback fits your situation and then make a concern which contains all the "series of events" that you want to occur. Furthermore, include that concern on the model that needs it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: It is not always desirable to run callback each time user created. There are situations where database record creation is not equals to registration. For example in unit tests. So, it's better to separate database manipulations (in active record) and business logic.

Comment: Appreciate the input.